# Python scaling to a fixed range, while keeping mean close to 0

Tags: python, scale, mean, normalization

Python experts,

Similar questions have been asked multiple times, but I couldn't find an ideal solution to my problem. I have a long series of mean normalized data (mean of 0, range of [-6, 11]), and I'd like to transform them to meet the following set of criteria simultaneously:

- Range of [-3, 3]
- Mean of 0 (stdev doesn't have to be 1)
- Remaining original distribution as much as possible

Currently, if I do min-max normalization, the range fits, but the mean drifted.

Any suggestions or tips?

Thanks much in advance!

Comment: There is a contradiction built into these three points. The range of your distribution is skewed ([-6, 11] with zero mean). You want it unskewed, with the same mean, yet keeping the original distribution. You have to sacrifice something here

Comment: I see your point, Marat.  Probably I have to live with the drifted mean (0,55 after min-max normalization).  Thanks for the reminder.  No perfect solution here.